# Scrolling with mouse in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Is there any way to scroll with mouse or keyboard in draw.io? So far the only way I found to do scrolling in draw.io is to use the diagram thumbnail at bottom right corner of the page.

Comment: Are there not any scrollbars in the browser?

Comment: There are. But you have to move with the mouse, aim to the scroll bar and do the scrolling.

I'm looking towards, if someone knows (hidden?) functionality like "hold Ctrl and then drag with the mouse". I've tried all possible combinations with no success so far, maybe JavaScript does not allow that.

So I decided to ask, if someone knows a better way to scroll "on the spot" with mouse or keyboard, without aiming to scrollbars and/or going to the preview, where you can move the view port.

Comment: Right click and drag?

Comment: That's it! Please propose that as an answer, so other people could find it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right mouse click (or equivalent on single button mouse) and drag while holding the button.